# Control Access to CiviCRM functions/actions available to Contacts

Tags: drupal, acl, roles

We have Drupal-CiviCrm setup with the sample data + Webform and WebForm_CiviCRM and have successfully created a webform which displays a form that allows you to filter the list by Org or Contact name

Now not having much experience with Drupal or CiviCRM I am trying to work out how I can allow a CiviCRM Contact to Manage contacts she has access to
eg take the Deforest Family where Ms. Alida Deforest can view and update information about Deforest family.

How do I allow Alida to do this when she comes to the website.
Further once this is set up how can you restrict Alida from changing (eg) relationships

Please be specific as the documentation around Drupal Roles - CiviCRM ACls doesnt seem to provide an end-to-end example.

Answer (score 1):

The way we approach self-management is

- use CiviCRM Permissioned Relationships extension
- in Views set up a display using the above relationships as View Relationships so you get a list of 'my' contacts
- set a Filter on Drupal user to 'is current user'
- provide the user with a block which will show them 'their children' and which provides links to a webform which will populate the URL with the ID of the child and hence allow them to edit 'their' child

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a way to do this for the [CiviCRM Entity project](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity)

I'm in the middle development which will bring big improvements to editing CiviCRM data from Drupal forms. There is much in place, but the allowance of custom permissions such as your case is not done yet. 
Watch for a new release to the -dev branch, coming within a week or two...

There will be a solution for this real soon!

Comment: Hi @jackrabbithanna  My current dilemma is whether to focus on Webforms_CIVICRM or Entities.  I can see there is probably more flexibilty with Entities given several hours of experimenting with Webforms_CiviCRM.  Would like to hear/see what others have achieved with CiviCRM in a self-servicing mode - ie using Drupal 'forms' to allow select users to 'manage' or request changes to CiviCRM records